# "App not installed" message when installed apk

Tags: android

So I have an app on the Play Store that I released about a week ago. I've done a ton of work to to it since and I'm basically going to rebrand it a bit.

When I first released the app, I put it up on the app store with the name "First Name of App" (obviously not the correct name). I now have an update ready to publish with a lot of changes, and one change is that the app name is now "Second Name of App". It's all under the same package yet, I just changed the name using the Manifest.

I'm having an issue though with testing. Currently on my own phone, I have the version of the app that is currently on the Play Store installed.

I generated a signed APK using Android Studio (all with the same settings and key passwords and such). I then put that signed apk on my phone for testing, and when I try to install it I get the "App not installed" message.

---

Things I have tried:

- **Uninstalling the previous APK and then installing the newer version.** If I uninstall the Play Store version first, and then install the newer signed APK version, it installs fine. The problem with this though is that I lose the data that I had in the Play Store version. I can't have that.
- **Changing the "versionCode" and "versionName" numbers in the build.gradle.** I made sure both numbers are higher than what the Play Store version is, but I still get the same "App not installed" message.
- **Making sure the settings while generating the signed APK are the same.** All of the settings are exactly the same. The signature version checkboxes are both checked yet also, as they were with all previous versions.

---

Anyone have any ideas what could be going on? I really would like to release this update but I'm afraid if I just upload this signed apk to the store that everyone would have the same issue, and that they'd be forced to uninstall the current version they have (resulting in data loss).

Comment: Are you sure you never installed same app with different package structure? Usually this kind of message pops up when you install a new app with the same name but the different package structure. Thus android studio tries to run `adb shell uninstall 'current.package.name'` and fails to proceed. To solve this issue you need to run uninstall for all packages structure from `adb`

Comment: @deathangel908 By different package structure, does that just mean different activities inside the app? Because I did add a number of new activities to the app. The only version of the app on my phone currently is the one that is on the Play Store.

Comment: Nope it only inlcludes package structure that you specified in `manifest.xml`

Comment: Then in that case it should be fine. The only things that have changed in the manifest since the Play Store versionare the  <activity/> sections for the new Activities I added, and that the <application/>'s android:label is now "Second Name of App"

Comment: This is weird, because android studio (I assume you're using it) uninstalls apps by package name, which should work if you changed the signkey or app name. Just run manuall uninstall (from command line using `adb shell` and see what is says.

Comment: I'll be honest, I'm not familiar with adb shell at all. But uninstalling the app is what I'm trying to avoid since the users will have data that they'll want to keep.

Comment: Users don't need to unsintall it, if you're publishing app to playmarket google will take care of that. So can't mess up in production. You just need to uninstall the app manually (using `adb` shell) from the device you are performing testing on. Take a look at https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html

Comment: @deathangel908 So basically, the users that currently are using my app wont have to uninstall the app first to get the newer version if I release it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem seems that you are trying to install an APK with the same package name but different key and that creates a conflict. Android only considers an App to be the same if both package name and key signature are identical.

Keys are unique, even if you use the same settings and passwords each time you create a key a new **unique** key is created and it will be always different to the key you used in the Play Store release.

The only way to install the APK is to uninstall the Play Store version.

And that serves to emphasize how important it is to keep the key used in the Play Store, if you lose it you will not be able to upload new updates.

**UPDATE**

If your have "Google Play App Signing " activated for you app, the key used when an user installs the app from Play Store is different than the one you used to upload the release to the Play Console.

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423?hl=en

Comment: But they key is the same yet. I am using the exact same key store path as when I signed the original release version. That app_key.jks file is also the same date modified, so it hasn't changed at all since.

Comment: Google Play App Signing is enabled for this app. If the key is different, how am I supposed to test the app on an actual device? I mean, the app works using all the emulators just fine, so it shouldn't be an issue. I read through through that link though and it makes me just wish I didn't enable Google Play App signing (which you can't even disable after). So I guess my question now is, if I upload this new version's signed apk to the Play Store, will people have to uninstall the previous version first?

Comment: No, the version that people will install from Play Store will have the same key that previous releases, but different that the one you use for the upload. The only way I know to test changes at home/work is to uninstall the Play Store version.

Answer (score 0):

Have you by chance changed the minimum SDK version or anything like that? I've had a similar issue. I've an app on the PlayStore which I tried upgrading with an APK with the same signature as that of the PlayStore version but a different minimum SDK version. When I tried installing I get the 'app not installed' error. I then uploaded this APK on the PlayStore. On my device, the app on the PlayStore now shows two options 'Uninstall' and 'Open'. Due to your conflict, users will have to first uninstall the app and install it again. There will be no 'Update' option due to the conflict. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

### Similar Issue

- Android Phone: Google Pixel3, Android 9

install youtube apk, but error:

`Application Not Installed` = `App Not Installed`

[image]

### Final Solution

- use `adb`'s `pm` to install apk

  - even same error, but can show/known the fail reason

    - then can find specific solution to fix it

#### Examples

here later encounter many error cases:

```
blueline:/storage/emulated/0/Download # pm install /data/local/tmp/com.google.android.youtube_16.29.36.apk
pm install /data/local/tmp/com.google.android.youtube_16.29.36.apk
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_VERSION_DOWNGRADE]
```

or:

```
blueline:/data/local/tmp # pm install youtube_16.29.36_addedDebuggable.apk
pm install youtube_16.29.36_addedDebuggable.apk
Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES: Failed to collect certificates from /data/app/vmdl445467286.tmp/base.apk: Attempt to get length of null array]
```

then google it and find specific solution to fix it, install apk successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered similar problem. But I figured it out by connecting the phone and see the logs via Android Studio. Then I found a suspicious log : "Package xxx signatures do not match previously installed version; ignoring!" And I resolve it by manually uninstall previous version info via 'adb uninstall "com.xxx.xxxx"'.